# Is there a way to import data from different JS files using a variable?

Tags: javascript, import, export

Thank you for your time in looking at my question.

The following is simplified for clarity, but an explanation should answer the critical parts of my question.

Assume I have three JavaScript files: **box1.js**, **box2.js** and **box3.js** and each has data inside dealing with various details about the boxes.

Assume I have 3 html files also called **box1.html**, **box2.html** and **box3.html**.

I have a final file called **main.js** that does a large number of functions on the data inside the three box.js files. (area, volume, capacity etc etc etc)

Depending on which html file the user loads, I want the main.js to be able to read the correct box.js file.

In main.js file, I can use the following to get information about box1:

`import { height, width, depth, material } from './box1.js';`

Then, I would use height, width, depth and material as variables in my main.js file. This is working properly.

However, depending which html file is loaded I would want to read the appropriate box.js file.

I know that I can't just include an import statement for each of the three files, and it doesn't seem to work if I create a variable first and use it in place of the path string. ( I get the error: "Unexpected identifier".)

The structure, array names and variables inside all three files are identical. Only the values in the arrays are different.

I also only need data from 1 file at load time. It will not change once main.js is loaded.

Is there a way to get main.js to read the correct file, and import the correct data?

**Note**: I have no particular need, that I'm aware of, to keep the box.js files as js files. If the answer to this question means these file change to be .txt or other file types, I can do that as long as I can still get the data into array variables in main.js.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The module specifier (the `"./box1.js"` part of the `import` statement) must be a string *literal*, not just a string. That's so it can be statically analyzed.

In modern environments, though, if you need to decide what module to import from at runtime, you can use [*dynamic import*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports): `import()`:

```
const theModuleName = /*...runtime logic to determine whether to import ./box1.js, ./box2.js, or ./box3.js */;
import(theModuleName)
.then(({height, width, depth, material}) => {
    // ...use them here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // the module failed to load; report/handle error
});
```

As you can see, dynamic import returns a promise. The promise is fulfilled with a *module namespace object* for the module.

In *really* modern environments you can combine that with [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await):

```
const theModuleName = /*...runtime logic to determine whether to import ./box1.js, ./box2.js, or ./box3.js */;
const {height, width, depth, material} = await import(theModuleName);
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into modules (including dynamic import) in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 13 of my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. See my profile for links if you're interested.